# QGIS raster with corresponding string per index

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster GeoTIFF file containing indices from 0 to 10000. In a CSV file, I have a corresponding string for each index.

I'm searching for a solution in QGIS to be able to easily see the corresponding string when I click on a pixel. I there a way to do that without converting it to a polygon layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of native functionality that will do this. However, it can be achieved using PyQGIS by subclassing and extending the [`QgsMapToolEmitPoint`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMapToolEmitPoint.html) class.

This code is not the cleanest, but it gives a general idea.

It assumes that the canvas CRS and raster layer CRS are the same. If they are not, the point emitted by the click event will need to be transformed.

To use, run in the script editor by clicking [image]

Just like most other map tools, it can be deactivating by activating a different map tool (e.g. the pan tool).

```py
p = QgsProject.instance()
raster = p.mapLayersByName('raster')[0]    # change to the name of your raster layer
lut = p.mapLayersByName('look up')[0]      # change to the name of the table containing the strings

class ClickMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        # initialise the QgsMapToolEmitPoint constructor
        super(ClickMapTool, self).__init__(canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):        
        self.handleClick(event)
        
    def handleClick(self, event):
        # native method to convert screen coordinates to map coordinates
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(event.pos())

        prov = raster.dataProvider()

        # sample the raster at the coordinates of the mouse click
        sample = prov.sample(point, 1, raster.extent())   # assumes your raster and map cnavas have the same CRS

        # sample is a tuple, the first element is the raster value
        index = int(sample[0])
        
        # make a feature request on the lookup table where field index = the raster value
        req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(f'index = {index}')
        candidate_features = list(lut.getFeatures(req))
        
        # display value (of first matching feature) from a field called "string" - change to match your field name
        print(candidate_features[0]['string'])
        
# get reference to the map canvas
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

# instantiate custom map tool
click_tool = ClickMapTool(canvas)

# set the map tool on the canvas
canvas.setMapTool(click_tool)

# unset by activating another map tool (e.g. the pan tool)
```

##### Result

This example has only 7 values, but it should still perform reasonably well on a much larger table.

[image]

This is a very bare bones example. But it could be fleshed out to be activated by a button and to display the string in a toolbar instead of the Python console.